# Excel -- displaying date that is X months from today

Tags: excel

Any easy way to do this? In VBA I'd normally use dateadd() but since this is Excel, I don't have that function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function does the job:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2,MIN(DAY(A2),DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2+1,0))))
```

For example:

```
Date       Add Months   Result  
8/1/2012   6            =DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2,MIN(DAY(A2),DAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+B2+1,0))))
```

Result:

```
Date       Add Months   Result  
8/1/2012   6            2/1/2013
```

Comment: Nice, it handles February and leap years properly

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the EDATE worksheet function.  For example EDATE(DATE(2012,8,1),6) returns February 1, 2013.

Comment: This function requires the Analysis ToolPak.

Comment: Isn't Analysis ToolPak standard with most XL installs?

Comment: I'm addicted to Office 2003, which does not feature the ToolPak by default. Regarding newer Office version, I have honestly no idea :)

Comment: I believe that the functions (like EDATE) that used to require the Analysis ToolPak no longer do so as of Excel 2007.